# Get only a specific value out of a function call with multiple return values?

Tags: go

Given `swap`, a function that returns multiple values, and supposing it's part of some API I can't modify:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func swap(x, y string) (string, string) {
    return y, x
}

func main() {
    a, b := swap("hello", "world")
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Is it possible to use `swap` function and get only the first returned value, discarding the second one? I tried this:

```
func main() {
    a, b := swap("hello", "world")
    fmt.Println(a)
}

ERROR: prog.go:10: b declared and not used [process exited with non-zero status]
```

And this is not possible too:

```
a := swap("hello", "world")

ERROR: prog.go:10: multiple-value swap() in single-value context
```

How to deal with functions that return multiple values when I don't need all the returned parts?

---

Code is based on "[A tour of go - lesson 9](http://tour.golang.org/#9)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the blank identifier `_`:

```
a, _ := swap("hello", "world")
```

Everything assigned to the blank identifier is silently discarded without a warning being raised. You can also use the blank identifier to add padding to structures:

```
struct {
    a byte
    b byte
    c byte
    _ byte // padding
}
```

Another usage of the blank identifier is to discard return values when initializing global variables:

```
var foo, _ = foo.NewFoo() // ignore error returned by NewFoo()
```

And when only one value of a range is required:

```
for _, v := range mySlice { }
```

Comment: what if I want to use the function returning multi-value in another function - in one line only?

Comment: @KrishnaGupta You can use the `;` statement separator: `foo, _ = bar(); baz(foo)`.  Otherwise, I believe there is no practical way.

Answer (score 0):

In case we don't want to use any extra variable (e.g. assigning to a map key), then we can use Immediately Invoked function expression (IIFE).

```
searchParams[v] = func(i int64, err error) int { return int(i) }(strconv.ParseInt("100", 10, 0))
```